# How to limit the number of notifications in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have tried the `->limit(4)` methods, but that doesn't seem to work

```
@foreach(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications()->limit(4) as $notification)
    <li>
        <a href="profile.html">
           <div>
              {{ $notification->data['message'] }}<span class="pull-right text-muted small">{{ time_elapsed_string($notification->created_at) }}</span>
           </div>
        </a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Tack on a `->get()` call as well. :)

Answer (score 9):

You do not execute the query here:

```
@foreach(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications()->take(4)->get() as $notification)
```

Also, you [shouldn't run queries in Blade files](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#do-not-execute-queries-in-blade-templates-and-use-eager-loading-n--1-problem).

Answer (score 6):

It's hard to say what `unreadNotifications` really returns but if it's collection you could use:

```
@foreach(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications()->take(4) as $notification)
```

and if it's relationship you could use:

```
@foreach(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications()->take(4)->get() as $notification)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
foreach(\Auth::user()->unreadNotifications->take(1) as $data){echo $data->id;}
```